# How to perform multiple queries with Apollo graphql HOC?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, react-hoc

I'm writing a web app and I need to query Apollo's local state as well as remote API. Apollo `graphql` HOC does not allow to send multiple queries but offers some `compose` function. But it seems that `@apollo/react-hoc` package does not have it. Scripting local state request into remote one does not work unfortunately (according to DevTools, request is sent, but no data is provided). Redux's `compose` does not help anyway (well, it's clear for me why so). What is the best way to solve this problem **WITHOUT** React hooks?

Comment: do you want multiple queries to run concurrently, or chained together?

Comment: @DamianGreen it can be either concurrent or API first, then local

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of your question, you can create multiple declarative `<Query>` components within your React component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the @apollo/react-hoc [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hoc), it seems you are able to run multiple queries by nesting one inside another.

By default `graphql` hooks injects data as a `data` prop so for multiple queries it will not  work without additional configuration. `config.name` comes to the rescue so you can specify different names for the injected props instead of `data`.

```
export default(
  graphql(
    query1, 
    {name: "data1"}
  )(
    graphql(
      query2, 
      {name: "data2"}
    )(YourComponent)
  )
)
```

Looks way too verbose. So `recompose`'s (essentially redux) `compose` will help you:

```
export default compose(
  graphql(query1, {name: "data1"}),
  graphql(query2, {name: "data2"})
)(YourComponent);
```

To tell the truth, this approach (with `compose`) is described in their docs but since it's placed somewhere in the middle where `config` is described, I believe it's better to put examples here for anyone to find when searching for the topic.

Comment: Note that the example in the docs actually uses the `compose` function from `recompose`, not `redux`, although the two are basically the [same](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/src/packages/recompose/compose.js) [thing](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/compose.ts).

Comment: yeah, nice catch. also thank you for adding link to docs, missed that.

Comment: @skyboyer these queries will run concurrently or be chained together. Means the second query will wait for the completion of the first query?

Comment: @KrishanKantSharma sequentially. If you want to have them running in parallel, [use hooks](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries) - your component may have any amount of hooks that will pull unrelated data in parallel.